# Unable to toggle multi-selectable dropdown with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a python function using selenium webdriver that selects one or several options in a drop-down menu. It is the second menu from the top at this web-page http://borsdata.se. Inspect gives med this html-code for the menu:

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                <!-- ngIf: !companyFilterCtrl.selectedMarketsName --><span ng-if="!companyFilterCtrl.selectedMarketsName" class="ng-scope">
                    <span>Alla Listor</span>
                </span><!-- end ngIf: !companyFilterCtrl.selectedMarketsName -->
                <!-- ngIf: companyFilterCtrl.selectedMarketsName -->
                <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

I have tried a number of different approaches with ChroPath as a guide but nothing seems to work. Eventually I even tried the ugly key-stroke based solution below which failed as well. In this case the DOWN-keys doesn't seem to have any effect after selecting the first item. Below is naive attempt to select the item 'Sverige' in the menu:

```
# select this menu with xpath
country_menu = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='MainMid1']/div[@id='CenterMid1']/div[@class='ng-scope']/div[@id='CompList']/div[@id='CompListTop']/div[2]/button[1]")

# attempt to use keyboard emulation to select an item in the menu
country_menu.click()   
country_menu.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)  # this opens the menu - works    
country_menu.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)   # this selects the first (default) item - works
time.sleep(1)
country_menu.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)   # this has no effect...
country_menu.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
country_menu.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)  
country_menu.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

Any suggestion for a working solution is greatly appreciated, preferably one that is structured differently than the (non-working) one I provided here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick working example I threw together to give you an idea of how to do this. The locators aren't the best but I leave that up to you to modify as you see fit:

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ActionChains

```
country1 = 'Sverige'
country2 = 'Danmark'

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://borsdata.se/')

menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#CompListTop div.multi-click')
button = menu.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
button.click()

dropdown = menu.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.dropdown-menu')
options = dropdown.find_elements_by_css_selector('li > a')
element1, element2 = None, None
for option in options:
    if country1 in option.text:
        element1 = option
    elif country2 in option.text:
        element2 = option

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.click(element1).click(element2).perform()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Brilliant Lucas, that worked beautifully. Big thanks!